# Ansible running process as wrong user

Tags: ansible

I have the below playbook, the problem is that last task that is supposed to start the process does not run the process as the NGINX_USER, it always runs as root, which was never specified anywhere. I check with `ps aux | grep nginx`. And when it does this I get a `Forbidden error`.

And when I try to force it to become user like in the commented out code, it gets stuck and won't complete.

How do I ensure that ansbile always runs with the correct users

```
- name: Install Nginx Ubuntu
  hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ NGINX_USER }}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  connection: ssh
  vars:
    NGINX_VERSION: nginx-1.17.10
    NGINX_SBIN_PATH: /usr/sbin/
    NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH: /var/log/nginx/error.log
    NGINX_HTTP_LOG_PATH: /var/log/nginx/access.log
    NGINX_PID_PATH: /var/run/nginx.pid
  vars_files:
    - ../vars/global.yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Check if Nginx Exists
      stat: path=/etc/init.d/nginx
      register: nginx_status

    - name: Stop nginx Service
      service: name=nginx state=stopped
      when: nginx_status.stat.exists
      register: service_stopped

    - name: Make sure a systemd is not running
      systemd:
        state: stopped
        name: nginx

    - name: Install aptitude using apt
      apt:
        name: aptitude
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
        force_apt_get: yes

    - name: Update apt repo
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 3600

    - name: Install required system packages
      apt: name={{ item }} state=latest update_cache=yes
      loop:
        [
          "build-essential",
          "libpcre3",
          "libpcre3-dev",
          "zlib1g",
          "zlib1g-dev",
          "libssl-dev",
        ]

    - name: Download nginx source
      get_url:
        url: "http://nginx.org/download/{{ NGINX_VERSION }}.tar.gz"
        dest: "/tmp/{{ NGINX_VERSION }}.tar.gz"

    - name: Unpacking NGINX
      unarchive:
        copy: no
        dest: /tmp/
        src: "/tmp/{{ NGINX_VERSION }}.tar.gz"

    - name: Configure NGINX source with custom modules
      command: "./configure  --prefix=/nginx --sbin-path={{ NGINX_SBIN_PATH }} --error-log-path={{ NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH }} --http-log-path={{ NGINX_HTTP_LOG_PATH }} --with-pcre
      --pid-path={{ NGINX_PID_PATH }} --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module"
      args:
        chdir: "/tmp/{{ NGINX_VERSION }}"

    - name: Make NGINX
      become: yes
      shell: make && make install
      args:
        chdir: "/tmp/{{ NGINX_VERSION }}"

    - name: Create directories"
      file:
        path: "{{ item.dir }}"
        state: directory
        owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
        group: "{{ item.group }}"
        mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
      with_items:
        - { dir: "/usr/local/nginx/html", owner: "{{ SYSTEM_USER }}", group: "{{ SYSTEM_USER_GROUP }}", mode: 755}
        - { dir: "/nginx", owner: "{{ NGINX_USER }}", group: "{{ NGINX_USER }}", mode: 755}

    - name: Copy nginx files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
        owner: "{{ NGINX_USER }}"
        group: "{{ NGINX_USER }}"
        mode: 755
      with_items:
        # - { src: "./conf/nginx.conf", dest: "{{ NGINX_CONF_PATH }}" }
        - { src: "./www/", dest: "/nginx/html" }
        - { src: "./scripts/nginx.service", dest: "/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service" }

    - name: Start NGINX
      # become: true
      # become_user: "{{ NGINX_USER }}"
      # become_method: sudo
      systemd:
        state: started
        name: nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you specify "become: yes" on the play level every task will be be executed as the become_user, which defaults to root. Try your start task with `become: false` :

```
   - name: Start NGINX
      become: false
      systemd:
        state: started
        name: nginx
```

Reading your code I would suspect "Make sure a systemd is not running" would fail as well with the become settings you show.